# Json schema validation shows no errors

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

I'm using Ajv version 6.10.2 to validate a simple Json schema that is separated in two files, but the thing is that I don't get the errors when doing the validation even though the json that I use to test is wrong.

This are the two parts of the schema:

root.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://test.com/schemas/root.json",
  "title": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "entrypoint": { "$ref": "entrypoint.json" }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": ["entrypoint"]
}
```

entrypoint.json

```
{
  "$id": "http://test.com/schemas/entrypoint.json",
  "description": "test object",
  "type": "string"
}
```

I instantiate Ajv like this

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';
import root from './root.json';
import entrypoint from './entrypoint.json';

const ajv = new Ajv({
  allErrors: true,
  schemas: [
   test,
   entrypoint,
  ],
});
```

This is the validation call

```
const validate = ajv.getSchema('http://test.com/schemas/root.json');
```

And this is the json used to test against the schema

```
{
    entrypoint: '',
    incorrect: {}
}
```

It comes out as invalid but it doesn't show no errors, I've been going over it for a long time but I haven't found a reason.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It looks like you're loading the file you're testing as a schema object

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: The schema defines what a JSON should look like - similar to 'entrypoint'. Then you validate your test.json against entrypoint. Remove test from the list of schemas.

Comment: I think I confused you, test.json is the root of the schema, not the test object, I'm going to fix the example.

Comment: I edited the example to reflect what I meant. @Kieveli

Comment: You need to add the `entrypoint.json` schema to the Ajv instance. Via addSchema IIRC

Comment: @customcommander but I'm doing that when instantiating Avj with schemas

Comment: You have added schemas in the correct way, but I can't see in your code where you have loaded in the schemas to the variables `test` and `entrypoint`. Please update your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: I would also recomend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - Currently I cannot reproduce your problem because you haven't included all the code. Consider providing more code AND a jsfiddle / jsbin showing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, you have no schema with the $id of `http://test.com/schemas/test.json`. You need to pass in the identifier (in your case, the full URI) of the schema you wish to use for validation into `getSchema`.

I can see you've copied from the documentation the URI shown as an example.

Comment: This assumes you've imported the JSON correctly. I've added a comment on your question.